# Add properties to each function (extend function)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making class for phyton script to manipulate AutoCAD. I had different function before for each action but I decided to make it as object to be more readable in script. I found myself repeating part of the code all the time and I was wondering how I can code this different way so that each function get LAYER and LINETYPE_SCALE automatically so I do not need to rewrite it all the time because there will be much more functions and all of them will have that part of code. Also I want to be able to change the code in one place if I need to. Thank you

```
class Draw:
    def Rectangle(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        rectangle = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(aDouble(
            X, Y,
            X, Y + HEIGHT,
            X + WIDTH, Y + HEIGHT,
            X + WIDTH, Y,
            X, Y
        ))
        rectangle.Layer = LAYER
        rectangle.LinetypeScale = LINETYPE_SCALE
        return rectangle

    def Square(X, Y, WIDTH, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        square = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(aDouble(
            X, Y, 
            X, Y + WIDTH,
            X + WIDTH, Y + WIDTH,
            X + WIDTH, Y,
            X, Y
        ))
        square.Layer = LAYER
        square.LinetypeScale = LINETYPE_SCALE
        return square

    def Circle(X, Y, RADIUS, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        circle = acad.model.AddCircle(APoint(X, Y), RADIUS)
        circle.Layer = LAYER
        circle.LinetypeScale = LINETYPE_SCALE
        return circle

    def Polyline(POINTS, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        polyline = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolylin(aDouble(POINTS))
        polyline.Layer = LAYER
        polyline.LinetypeScale = LINETYPE_SCALE
        return polyline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for solution which could help you to avoid copy paste of same code and here it is:

```py
class Draw:
    @staticmethod
    def _finalize(ENTITY, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        ENTITY.Layer = LAYER
        ENTITY.LinetypeScale = LINETYPE_SCALE
        return ENTITY

    @staticmethod
    def Rectangle(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        rectangle = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(aDouble(
            X, Y,
            X, Y + HEIGHT,
            X + WIDTH, Y + HEIGHT,
            X + WIDTH, Y,
            X, Y
        ))
        return Draw._finalize(rectangle, LAYER, LINETYPE_SCALE)

    @staticmethod
    def Square(X, Y, WIDTH, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        return Draw.Rectangle(X, Y, WIDTH, WIDTH, LAYER, LINETYPE_SCALE)

    @staticmethod
    def Circle(X, Y, RADIUS, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        circle = acad.model.AddCircle(APoint(X, Y), RADIUS)
        return Draw._finalize(circle, LAYER, LINETYPE_SCALE)

    @staticmethod
    def Polyline(POINTS, LAYER=0, LINETYPE_SCALE=1):
        polyline = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolylin(aDouble(POINTS))
        return Draw._finalize(polyline, LAYER, LINETYPE_SCALE)
```

BUT! Class with bunch of static methods <s>*should*</s>could be easily replaced with module containing functions. At all, I'd prefer to have separate class for each shape, it seems to be better solution.

Anyway, improving working code is not an object at Stack Overflow, you can post a question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below: use abstract base class . Code was **not** tested since I dont have `acad` API.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Shape(ABC):
    def __init__(self, layer=0, line_type_scale=1):
        self.layer = layer
        self.line_type_scale = line_type_scale

    @abstractmethod
    def draw():
        pass


def Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius,layer,line_type_scale):
        super().__init__(layer,line_type_scale)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.raduis = radius
    def draw():
        circle = acad.model.AddCircle(APoint(self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        circle.Layer = self.layer
        circle.LinetypeScale = self.line_type_scale
        return circle
```

Comment: I was hoping more to achieve something like to write some function lats sat that is called `props` that hold all props and then just on return to append that 2 lines to object to use something like `return circle.props(LAYER, LINETYPE_SCALE)` so i do not need to write that 2 lines all the time.

Comment: Look at partial function - it may be the direction you will go. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partial-functions-python/

Comment: @Klak031, you want [this](https://tio.run/##nZJda4MwFIbv@ytyqUxkYzdjIEyqTEGcqKPrVcli2gZSdTEy3J938SttlbZuuRA5OefJe95z8orvs/TxKWd1jSgsCmAx@P28AOK8FBxygg5YpCRtJMFbsNmSFFLygxXbj914rQHPXNuhcS9@XN@O14G9iZamZxsPasdpTpere7DCDBhdyeSSpJhXOY4QpLhJOsPJbIZ5ydK@aHFFaYgRh@mOYuVDA0LnyrViRwOO7b468TzZbEAIORDBRD9kCaa6mSQe2e35CjffIKMVFdoVaGXlp3hOljenfXsSAXeDjvMrEe9lzkmZcmVAVceGNYPVj9OTrfVOjH1Qr1kbfZWQjXyd5@dRyoXxnNL@pGlJGJKw0LTc92ieKNQWTibc88wgIylvserAveVtR/xPE3KXgjfXj2c2kPdFM5ZU7mjHv7klA/pSL3X9Cw). It's possible to make it in that way, but architecturally it's better to have separate classes for each shape.

Comment: @OlvinRoght can you post that as answer so I can accept as right one. That's exactly what I was looking for. I prefer like this so when I finish framework I can use it easy like `Draw.Rectangle()` `Draw.Circle()` etc. other class will be then `Dimension.Veritcal()` `Dimension.Horizontal()` etc. then for example `Layer.New()` `Layer.Rename()` `Layer.Delete()` etc...

Comment: @Klak031, answer is [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69605375/10824407), further questions regarding code architecture better to ask at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).